# Is there away to include javascript color code inside a LaTeX document?

Tags: packages

I would like to know how to include javascript color code inside a LaTeX document ?

[image: javascript]

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "javascript color code"? Do you want to show some JavaScript code in a listing and have the listing be colored the way an IDE would? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: If you mean HTML colors, then take a look at package `xcolor`. It adds the color model "HTML".

Comment: @TH I want my JavaScript code looks like in a listing and has the listing be colored the way an IDE would.